# multithreading in tcp server in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp

I have written this class for Multithreaded tcp server in C++ .. and compile by ::

```
g++ -o server server.cpp -lpthread
```

BUT I get the following errors ::

```
invalid conversion from "void*" to "void* (*)(void*)"
initializing argument 3 of "int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)"
```

What should I do ?? My Code ::

```
#include "PracticalSocket.h" 
#include <iostream>          
#include <cstdlib>           
#include <pthread.h>         
using namespace std;

class MultiThreadedServer{

private:
static const int RCVBUFSIZE = 1024;
string agent_ip;
int agent_port;

public:

string startServer(unsigned short port, string agentIP, int agentPort)
{
agent_ip = agentIP;
agent_port=agentPort;

try 
{
    TCPServerSocket servSock(port);   // Socket descriptor for server  

    for (;;) 
    {   
        // Create separate memory for client argument  
        TCPSocket *clntSock = servSock.accept();  
        pthread_t threadID;              
        if (pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, (void*) &ThreadMain,(void *) &clntSock) != 0) 
        {
            cerr << "Unable to create thread" << endl; 
            exit(1);
        }

    }
} 
catch (SocketException &e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
// NOT REACHED
}


// TCP client handling function
void static HandleTCPClient(TCPSocket *sock) 
{
cout << "Handling client ";
try 
{
    cout<<"Foreign address: "<< sock->getForeignAddress() << ":";
} 
catch (SocketException &e) 
{
    cerr << "Unable to get foreign address" << endl;
}
try 
{
    cout<<"Foreign port: "<< sock->getForeignPort();
} 
catch (SocketException &e)
{
    cerr << "Unable to get foreign port" << endl;
}
cout << " with thread " << pthread_self() << endl;

char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
int recvMsgSize;
while ((recvMsgSize = sock->recv(echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE)) > 0) 
{
    cout<<"echoBuffer::::"<<echoBuffer;
    //sock->send(echoBuffer, recvMsgSize);
}
   // Destructor closes socket
 }

 static void ThreadMain(void *clntSock)
 {
// Guarantees that thread resources are deallocated upon return  
pthread_detach(pthread_self()); 

// Extract socket file descriptor from argument  
HandleTCPClient((TCPSocket *) clntSock);

delete (TCPSocket *) clntSock;
//return NULL;
 }



 };
```

Comment: Whe the cast? Just say `ThreadMain`, or perhaps `&MultiThreadedServer::ThreadMain`.

Comment: Use `-pthread` when both compiling and linking instead of `-lpthread`, the latter is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the method name directly without a cast:

```
pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, ThreadMain,(void *) &clntSock)
```

Also the method needs to return `void*` not `void`:

```
static void* ThreadMain(void *clntSock)
```

Comment: thanks but ... i am getting this error and can not create the object file after compilation :::     /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You don't need that remaining `(void *)` cast either.

Comment: @RRR: this means you don't have a main method in your file.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, (void*) &ThreadMain,(void *) &clntSock)
```

pthread_create expects a pointer to function (ThreadMain) of the correct signature.

```
pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, MyThreadedServer::ThreadMain, (void *) &clntSock)
```

This should be enough.

EDIT: as pointed out by Tudor in his answer, the return type of the ThreadMain function must be void*:

```
void* ThreadMain(void* d);
```

Comment: Also, as i side note.. unless this code is just for educational purposes i advise you to check out boost.asio for much easier, cross-platform multi-threaded applications (especially servers): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html

Comment: @RRR: Also the method should return void*, as I've said in my answer.

Comment: Your compilation command looks fine. Take a look at my old implementation of a wrapper around thread: http://code.google.com/p/craplib/source/browse/trunk/Thread.cpp

Comment: Oh, yeah. I missed that. Tudor is right. Must be void* return.

Comment: thanks BUT ..can not create the object file after compilation,    Now i am getting this error:::                                 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../crt1.o: In function _start': (.text+0x18): undefined reference to main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That's another problem: you made a program without a main() function, and the call to gcc uses the default behavior: compile AND link. If you just want to compile for later use, add the -c option.